# WooCommerce: how to add product price to cart via URL?

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I found the ability to add to the cart through URL:

```
http://yoururl.com/cart/?add-to-cart=ID
```

I also found how to add quantity and attributes using this link, but can't find a way to add a price.
How to use this link to add a price to the cart?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a simple product, the price is the one declared.

If it is a variable product, you can use the variation id.

```
> href=”http://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=88″
```

You can find more info about that, here. https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/

If is not working, please provide what code are you trying to use and more info about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the product to cart with a custom price, you can't via URL.
You need to do it via PHP (if you are currently using JS, you will need to use an AJAX function like jQuery $.post and call a PHP function).

In the PHP function you add the product:

```
function addtocart(){
   $cart_item_data['custom_price'] = 5678;
   WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, 0, array(), $cart_item_data);
}
```

You will also need to modify the price in the cart

```
// Change product price in the cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_price_function' );

function change_price_function( $_cart ){
        // loop through the cart_contents
        foreach ( $_cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $value ) {       
            $value['data']->set_price($value['custom_price']);
        }
    }
```